# Usage of "throw the net wide"

Tags: expressions

Can I have an example of a context in which the expression *throw the net wide* is used? I have heard it in passing but it is not clear to me what was meant.

Comment: I've always heard / read it as "cast the net wide"....

Comment: it refers to a fish net maybe?

Comment: @Mitch maybe. Have you read the answers?

Comment: @slim: what, you mean there's another possibility? (when I made my comment I had missed you mention of the fishing). So my comment was more to the obviousness of the metaphor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "We really need to find strong candidates for this job, so let's throw the net wide."

Meaning: "Let's look in as many places as possible for job candidates."

It is a metaphor for fishing with a net. The wider you throw the net, the larger an area of water it will cover, so the more likely you are to catch a fish.

Comment: Albeit all the more likely that you'll be catching other stuff too. "Throw the net wide" basically indicates that you're being less discriminating in your initial selection.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think I've ever heard "throw the net wide". I've always heard it as, "throw a wide net".

But then I just did the ever-popular [ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=throw+the+net+wide%2Cthrow+a+wide+net&year_start=1850&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3) thing and it shows "throw the net wide" at zero usage up to about 1955, but surging in popularity and intermittently passing "throw a wide net". Huh.

Comment: haha - I'd never heard *"throw a wide net"* before, so I thought your NGram was quite surprising. I guess you won't like [this one](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cast+a+wide+net%2Cthrow+a+wide+net&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) then, since it shows conclusively that the word **"cast"** was always the dominant verb, even if the other words get rearranged in variations of the idiom.

Comment: I, too, have always heard "___ a wide net", not "___ the net wide" -- but, like FumbleFingers, my ___ is "cast", not "throw". (Of course, his/her Ngram is cheating slightly -- "cast" is both plain-form and preterite, whereas "throw" is only plain-form -- but "casts" vs. "throws" gives the same result.)